# How to configure an Eclipse Java format to use two spaces after a sentence in comments?

Tags: java, eclipse, formatting, format, comments

There doesn't appear to be a setting in the Eclipse Java formatter that indicates the number of spaces to use after a sentence within a comment block.  I want Eclipse to use two spaces, and it seems to default to one.  Am I overlooking a setting?

I'm not looking for arguments as to why I should use [one space](http://www.slate.com/articles/technology/technology/2011/01/space_invaders.html) or [two spaces](http://stevelosh.com/blog/2012/10/why-i-two-space/).  I just want to know how to get Eclipse to use two!

As it is now, here's an example of what Eclipse is doing to thousands of lines of comments:
[image: Eclipse formats two spaces as one]

Comment: I don't think this is possible. No such option in formatter. Is formatter changing your comments? Disable formatting of comments

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, Eclipse does not provide this by default. You can write your own formatter to do anything specific.